# Knockout register inserted element with other function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using Knockout to display some tags for an array of images. each tag will have a popup that gives more information about the tag. The elements is registered with popup class the following way:

```
function RegisterCharacterPopups() {
    $('[data-characterid]').each(function() {
        var cId = $(this).data('characterid');
        var placement = $(this).data('position');
        if (placement == null || placement == undefined) {
            placement = "top-center";
        }
        $(this).PopUp({
            url: "/Ajax/CharacterPop/" + cId,
            position: placement,
        });
    });
}
```

And i have added this to my constructor of the view model that contains the tags:

```
// Hook on to update of Tags
ko.computed(() => {
    var test = this.Tags();
    RegisterCharacterPopups();
    console.log("Tags updated");
});
```

I can see the methods is executed, but the tags do not register with the popup. if it force the Tags to update again, will it work though!
I think the problem is that this method in executed the first time, before the elements are in the html.
How can I fix this, so it will wait for the elements to be inserted before it executes it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: a custom binding

```
ko.bindingHandlers['tagpop'] = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, vm, context) {
        var data = valueAccessor();
        $(element).PopUp({
            url: "/Ajax/CharacterPop/" + data.id,
            position: data.placement,
        });

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    }
};
```

Comment: and now your function is executed after the html is rendered??